# WordLadder in Java

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble with solving the WordLadder problem that many people probably know about.

**Word ladder (also known as Doublets, word-links, or Word golf) is a word game invented by Lewis Carroll. A word ladder puzzle begins with two words, and to solve the puzzle one must find a chain of other words to link the two, in which two adjacent words (that is, words in successive steps) differ by one letter.**

Example would be going from --> cat, can, con, cog, dog

I found a tutorial online with the attached code below. I understand how breath-first search works, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the actual path from the starting word to the end word. The author is only trying to find the shortest ladder length, while I would like to know the words that actually correspond with that ladder path.

```
public int ladderLength(String start, String end, HashSet<String> dict) {
    if (dict.size() == 0)
        return 0;

    dict.add(end);

    LinkedList<String> wordQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<Integer> distanceQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    wordQueue.add(start);
    distanceQueue.add(1);

    //track the shortest path
    int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while (!wordQueue.isEmpty()) {
        String currWord = wordQueue.pop();
        Integer currDistance = distanceQueue.pop();

        if (currWord.equals(end)) {
            result = Math.min(result, currDistance);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < currWord.length(); i++) {
            char[] currCharArr = currWord.toCharArray();
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
                currCharArr[i] = c;

                String newWord = new String(currCharArr);
                if (dict.contains(newWord)) {
                    wordQueue.add(newWord);
                    distanceQueue.add(currDistance + 1);
                    dict.remove(newWord);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (result < Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        return result;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any future help!

Answer (score 1):

If performance isn't an issue, this might work for you.

```
public static LinkedList<String> ladderLength(String start, String end, HashSet<String> dict) {
    if (dict.size() == 0)
        return new LinkedList<String>();

    dict.add(end);

    LinkedList<String> wordQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<Integer> distanceQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> pathsQueue = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
    LinkedList<String> solution = new LinkedList<String>();

    wordQueue.add(start);
    distanceQueue.add(1);
    dict.remove(start);
    LinkedList<String> path = new LinkedList<String>();
    path.add(start);
    pathsQueue.add(path);

    //track the shortest path
    int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while (!wordQueue.isEmpty()) {
        String currWord = wordQueue.pop();
        Integer currDistance = distanceQueue.pop();
        LinkedList<String> currentPathQueue = pathsQueue.pop();

        if (currWord.equals(end)) {
            if (currDistance < result)
            {
                result = currDistance;
                solution = currentPathQueue;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < currWord.length(); i++) {
            char[] currCharArr = currWord.toCharArray();
            for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
                currCharArr[i] = c;
                LinkedList<String> currentPathQueueTemp = new LinkedList<String>(currentPathQueue);

                String newWord = new String(currCharArr);
                if (dict.contains(newWord)) {
                    wordQueue.add(newWord);
                    distanceQueue.add(currDistance + 1);
                    currentPathQueueTemp.add(newWord);
                    pathsQueue.add(currentPathQueueTemp);
                    dict.remove(newWord);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (result < Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        return solution;
    else
        return new LinkedList<String>();
}
```

Basically, what I did is very quickly add a queue of the paths taken. So as we add the lengths to the queue, we also add the current path to another queue. In this way we keep track of the paths. This is definitely not optimized, but it works.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't think to look at it like that. I was thinking about doing something with nodes and backtracking. It does work though. Thanks a lot for the help!